# Decoding URL containing unicode characters

Tags: unicode, python-2.7, escaping, cherrypy, mako

I have the following code in a Mako template:

```
<a href="#" onclick='getCompanyHTML("${fund.investments[inv_name].name | u}"); return false;'>${inv_name}</a>
```

This applies url escaping to  the name string of an object representing a company.  The resulting escaped string is then used in a url.  The Mako documentation states that url encoding is provided using `urllib.quote_plus(string.encode('utf-8'))`.

On the server I receive the company name part into the argument `investment_name`:

```
def Investment(client, fund_name, investment_name, **kwargs):
    client          = urllib.unquote_plus(client)
    fund_name       = urllib.unquote_plus(fund_name)
    investment_name = urllib.unquote_plus(investment_name)
```

I then use investment_name as a key back in to the same dictionary from which it was extracted in the template.

This works fine for all the standard cases, such as spaces, slashes, and single quotes in the company name.  However, it fails if the company name contains unicode characters outside of the ascii character set.

For instance, the url for company name "Eptisa Servicios de Ingeniería S.L." is rendered as "Eptisa+Servicios+de+Ingenier%C3%ADa+S.L."  When this value arrives back at the server, I'm reversing the url escaping but clearly failing to decode the unicode properly because my attempt to use the result as a dictionary key generates a key error.

I've tried adding unicode decoding in these two forms, without luck:

```
    investment_name = urllib.unquote_plus(investment_name.decode('utf-8'))
    investment_name = urllib.unquote_plus(investment_name.encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('utf-8'))
```

Can anyone suggest what I must do to "Eptisa+Servicios+de+Ingenier%C3%ADa+S.L." to turn it back into "Eptisa Servicios de Ingeniería S.L."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in the reverse order: first unquote then `.decode('utf-8')`

Do not mix bytes and Unicode strings.

#### Example

```
import urllib

q = "Eptisa+Servicios+de+Ingenier%C3%ADa+S.L."
b = urllib.unquote_plus(q)
u = b.decode("utf-8")
print u
```

Note: `print u` might produce UnicodeEncodeError. To fix it:

```
print u.encode(character_encoding_your_console_understands)
```

*Or* set `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable.

On Unix you could try `locale.getpreferredencoding()` as character encoding, on Windows see output of `chcp`

Comment: When I do `urllib.unquote_plus(investment_name).decode('utf-8')` then I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 28-29: ordinal not in range(128)` from the codecs module in the .decode('utf-8') call.

Comment: @LarryLustig: Try the code example above. What line produces the error? Is it `print u`?

Comment: Trying now.  I know that I can't print the unicode string to my term but if I can get the decode to work I should be okay (I'll confirm by using the result as a key into my dictionary).  Thanks for your help, results soon. . .

Comment: Result: your code works perfectly (including printing the Windows command console, go figure).  Looking a little deeper, I see that the string I'm unquoting and decoding (`q` in your sample code) is unicode whereas I assume that in your example it's string (I'm using 2.7).  If I take your code and turn `q` into a unicode string, it acts like my code.

Comment: I believe I have it now.  I need to first encode the string as `utf-8`, then `unquote_plus` it, then decode it again as `utf-8` back to unicode.

Comment: @LarryLustig: valid urls always contain characters within ascii range therefore it is safe to `q = q.encode('ascii') if isinstance(q, unicode) else q`